# WebSocket connection failure. Error during Websocket handshake. Response Code 403?

Tags: javascript, wordpress, websocket

This is the message I'm getting for my Wordpress site:

> "WebSocket connection to 'wss://public-api.wordpress.com/pinghub/wpcom/me/newest-note-data' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 403"

It's causing a fusion-slider on my homepage to forever try to load, but never shows up.

Note: Sometimes it does work and the console gets no errors, most of the time it doesn't.

I haven't been able to figure this out online, some people have similar issues, but not on the same platform. How do I go about fixing this. Let me know if there's additional information required.

Comment: Symilar thread https://wordpress.org/support/topic/websocket-connection-to-wsspublic-apiwordpresscompinghubwp-failed-403

Comment: Try contacting jetpack support https://jetpack.com/contact-support/

Comment: also you may have more luck on wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 12):

I was also seeing these notices as well, and here is the response I just received from Jetpack:

> We've found out that the Websocket console error is only displayed if you are not logged into WordPress.com. If you are, the error will be gone.
>
> We are working on a fix for this but I don't have an exact ETA on it. However, you can remain logged into WordPress.com and the console error won't be triggered.
>
> I hope it makes sense. Thank you very much for your understanding and patience. Cheers :)

So it's is indeed related to jetpack, and an unresolved issue that they are aware of.

Comment: Still no fix for this bug?

Comment: Still present to-date.

Comment: As of 2021 it is still an issue. I guess they don't care...

Answer (score 12):

I solved this issue by deactivating the Jetpack plugin & activating it again. Hope this helps!

Comment: Thanks, this helped (for now?) :).

Comment: That did not work me.

Answer (score 0):

Log out and log back in and the problem should be fixed.